# Disable dynamically generated buttons in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, dynamic

Each time a user selects a checkbox within a row of a table, and clicks save, it will generate a container which will hold the data in a specific format for that selected row.

Note: The data is coming in the table from JSON.

Similarly, the user will also have an option to add the data manually to the same container through a form.

Now, I all these containers or data holders will be appended to a parent container in the dom.

I need to swap each of these data containers, which I've achieved so far.
However, the buttons are not getting disabled or hidden for the first container and the last one.

Here's my script

```
<script>
    function getData(){
        $('input[name="articles"]:checked').map(function() {    
            var content =  JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(this.value));
            content+= '<div class="container parent><div class="row article-row"><div class="col-md-6 article data-col"><div class="row"><form class="form-horizontal"><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-md-4">Name:</label><div class="col-md-8 article-data">'+name+'</div></div></form></div></div><div class="col-md-6 article btn-col"><div class="row del-btn"><button class="btn btn-danger remove">Delete &nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button></div><div class="row updown-btn"><div class="btn-group"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm top-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span></button><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm down-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span></button></div></div></div></div></div>';                                     
            $('.box').html(content);
        });
        $('.remove').click(function(){
            $(this).parents('.parent').remove();
        });             
        resetEvents();
    }
function addName(){
    var name= $("#articleTitle").val();
    content +='<div class="container parent><div class="row article-row"><div class="col-md-6 article data-col"><div class="row"><form class="form-horizontal"><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-md-4">Name:</label><div class="col-md-8 article-data">'+Count+'</div></div></form></div></div><div class="col-md-6 article btn-col"><div class="row del-btn"><button class="btn btn-danger remove">Delete &nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button></div><div class="row updown-btn"><div class="btn-group"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm top-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span></button><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm down-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span></button></div></div></div></div></div>';
        $('.box').html(content);
        $('.removeArticle').click(function(){
        $(this).parents('.parent').remove();
    });

}
function handleEvents() {
    $(".top-btn, .down-btn").prop("disabled", false).show();    
    $(".parent:first").find(".top-btn").prop("disabled", true).hide();    
    $(".parent:last").find(".down-btn").prop("disabled", true).hide();
}
function resetEvents() {    
    $(".top-btn, .down-btn").unbind('click');    
    handleEvents();                 
    $('.down-btn').click(function() {
        var toMove1 = $(this).parents('.article-box');   
        $(toMove1).insertAfter($(toMove1).next());   
        handleEvents();
    });   
    $('.top-btn').click(function() {
        var toMove1 = $(this).parents('.article-box');
        $(toMove1).insertBefore($(toMove1).prev());
        handleEvents();
    });
}
</script>
```

The first data holder will not have a top one to swap with. Hence, the top button should be disabled or hidden.

Similarly, the last data holder will not have a down one to swap with. Hence, the down button should be disabled or hidden.

I'm not able to understand what's wrong with what I wrote?

Note: This works perfectly fine if I use hard-coded data holders rather than generating it on runtime.

Comment: Use delegated events instead of default events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a [delegated listener](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

```
$('NearestParentElementThatAppearsOnPageLoad').on('event', 'ElementToApplyListenerTo', function() {
  // Do something
});
```

Comment: ok...but how I do this in this case? I'm new to jQuery..so if you could help me write that?

Comment: @Sunny would need a working example to do that, rather than a list of functions.

Answer (score 1):

For dynamically generated elements use delegated event handlers like this:

```
$("body").on("click", selector, function() {
     //actions to do
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the complete code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
        <style>
            .parent {
                height: 25%;
                width: 90%;
                padding: 1%;
                margin-left: 1%;
                margin-top: 1%;
                border: 1px solid black;

            }

            .parent:nth-child(odd){
                background: skyblue;
            }

            .parent:nth-child(even){
                background: green;
            }

            .disabled-btn {
              cursor: not-allowed;
              opacity: 0.25%;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="getData()">Get data</button>
        <form>
            <label>Count: </label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="enter a count" id="mycount">
            <button onclick="saveData()">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <div class="box">

        </div>



    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var content = "";

        function getData(){

                for(var count=0; count<4; count++){

                content+= '<div class="container parent"><div class="row article-row"><div class="col-md-6 article data-col"><div class="row"><form class="form-horizontal"><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-md-4">Count:</label><div class="col-md-8 article-data">'+count+'</div></div></form></div></div><div class="col-md-6 article btn-col"><div class="row del-btn"><button class="btn btn-danger remove-btn">Delete &nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button></div><div class="row updown-btn"><div class="btn-group"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm top-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span></button><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm down-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span></button></div></div></div></div></div>';

                }
                $('.box').html(content);

            $('.remove-btn').click(function(){
                $(this).parents('.parent').remove();
            });


            resetEvents();
        }

        function saveData(){
            var count = $("#mycount").val();
            content+= '<div class="container parent"><div class="row article-row"><div class="col-md-6 article data-col"><div class="row"><form class="form-horizontal"><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-md-4">Count:</label><div class="col-md-8 article-data">'+count+'</div></div></form></div></div><div class="col-md-6 article btn-col"><div class="row del-btn"><button class="btn btn-danger remove-btn">Delete &nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button></div><div class="row updown-btn"><div class="btn-group"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm top-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span></button><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm down-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span></button></div></div></div></div></div>';

            $('.box').html(content);
            $('.remove-btn').click(function(){
                $(this).parents('.parent').remove();
            });
        }

        function handleEvents() {
                $(".top-btn, .down-btn").prop("disabled", false).show();
                $(".parent:first").find('.top-btn').attr('disabled','disabled');

                $(".parent:first").find(".top-btn").prop("disabled", true).hide();


                $(".parent:last").find(".down-btn").prop("disabled", true).hide();
            }


            function resetEvents() {

                $(".top-btn, .down-btn").unbind('click');

                handleEvents();

                $('.down-btn').click(function() {
                    var toMove1 = $(this).parents('.parent');

                    $(toMove1).insertAfter($(toMove1).next());

                    handleEvents();
                });

                $('.top-btn').click(function() {
                    var toMove1 = $(this).parents('.parent');

                    $(toMove1).insertBefore($(toMove1).prev());
                    handleEvents();
                });

            }


    </script>
    </body>
</html>


            resetEvents();
        }

        function saveData(){
            var count = $("#mycount").val();
            content+= '<div class="container parent><div class="row article-row"><div class="col-md-6 article data-col"><div class="row"><form class="form-horizontal"><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-md-4">Count:</label><div class="col-md-8 article-data">'+count+'</div></div></form></div></div><div class="col-md-6 article btn-col"><div class="row del-btn"><button class="btn btn-danger remove-btn">Delete &nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button></div><div class="row updown-btn"><div class="btn-group"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm top-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span></button><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm down-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span></button></div></div></div></div></div>';

            $('.box').html(content);
            $('.remove-btn').click(function(){
                $(this).parents('.parent').remove();
            });
        }

        function handleEvents() {
                $(".top-btn, .down-btn").prop("disabled", false).show();
                $(".parent:first").find('.top-btn').attr('disabled','disabled');

                $(".parent:first").find(".top-btn").prop("disabled", true).hide();


                $(".parent:last").find(".down-btn").prop("disabled", true).hide();
            }


            function resetEvents() {

                $(".top-btn, .down-btn").unbind('click');

                handleEvents();

                $('.down-btn').click(function() {
                    var toMove1 = $(this).parents('.parent');

                    $(toMove1).insertAfter($(toMove1).next());

                    handleEvents();
                });

                $('.top-btn').click(function() {
                    var toMove1 = $(this).parents('.parent');

                    $(toMove1).insertBefore($(toMove1).prev());
                    handleEvents();
                });

            }


    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also, the swap option on clicking top-btn, down-btn, deleting a data holder using X- button doesn't work when it's a dynamically generated content.